# KickFlip Framework not broadcasting

Tags: ios, objective-c, kickflip

In kickflip framework video board casting not happened when I stop the video its shows.

```
[Kickflip presentBroadcasterFromViewController:self ready:^(KFStream *stream) {
     NSLog(@"Stream is ready at URL: %@", stream.streamURL);
    if (stream.streamURL)
    {
        NSLog(@"Stream is ready at URL: %@", stream.streamURL);

    }
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError* error){
    if (!success)
    { 
        NSLog(@"Error setting up stream: %@", error);
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"Done broadcasting");

    }
}];
```

i am using above code,This code is mention in kickflip framework documentation.

Comment: Do you have an error? Which log is printed?

Comment: No,and it's shows "Done broadcasting".